# get selected presets in vue-date-picker. without using date calculations

Tags: vue.js

```
<VueDatePicker
  ref="datepicker"
              v-model="selectedDate"
              range
              month-name-format="long"
              placeholder="Select date"
              mode-height="650"
              :clearable="true"
              :format="format"
              :preset-ranges="presetRanges"
              :enable-time-picker="false"
              :teleport="true"
              :alt-position="customPosition"
              @cleared="clearDate"
            >
```

[image]

How do I get the selected preset range. I need the selected preset  **with out calculating the date** as calculating the date leads to presets overlapping eg: this week and last 7 days. So I need specifically which preset is clicked.

```
const presetRanges = ref([
      {
        label: 'Today',
        range: [new Date(), new Date()],
      },
      {
        label: 'This week',
        range: [startOfWeek(new Date()), new Date()],
      },
      {
        label: 'Last 7 days',
        range: [subDays(new Date

(), 6), new Date()],
  },
  {
    label: 'This month',
    range: [startOfMonth(new Date()), endOfMonth(new Date())],
  },
  {
    label: 'Last 6 months',
    range: [startOfMonth(subMonths(new Date(), 6)), new Date()],
  },
  {
    label: 'This year',
    range: [startOfYear(new Date()), endOfYear(new Date())],
  },
  {
    label: 'Last 12 months',
    range: [startOfMonth(subMonths(new Date(), 12)), new Date()],
  },
  {
    label: 'All time',
    range: [new Date('1990-12-31'), new Date()],
  },
]);
```